# Show object with unless and else Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to use unless with else statement. I want in the else statement to make sure the object is not nil first (so, it won't break) then it is not nil print the user.employers.first.name in the else.

```
<% unless user.employers.empty? || (user.employers.size < 2) %>
                <%= link_to user.employers.first.name,show_companies_user_path(user), "data-toggle" => "modal","data-target" => "#myModal" %>
                   (<%=user.employers.size %>)
              <% else %>
                <%= user.employers.present?%>
                 <%= user.employers.first.name %> # I want to show this
              <% end %>
```

Comment: Or it is better to use if elsif in this case?

Comment: It is better to use `if/else` in this case

Comment: https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#no-else-with-unless

Comment: The check to `#empty?` is unnecessary as well, because if it is empty, it will be `< 2`. As everyone else has said, don't do an unless/else statement.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `unless` that way, but `unless` - `else`is a very weird pattern. The whole point of `unless` is to have a simple shortcut for `if not` but if you have an `if *positive* else *alternative*` type pattern then starting with `unless` is a less readable than starting with `if`.

Answer (score 1):

I've never really seen this pattern before. You should do the `if` `else` pattern in my opinion. Just negate the logic behind unless and use `if`.